# Accessing Google Admin SDK Directory API on remote server

Tags: java, server, google-admin-sdk, google-workspace

I am trying to use directory API of GSuite to get all the employee information from a domain. I have followed this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/java) to do it. I am able to fetch the user information when i was deploying it in my local server.
There was a google link which i was supposed to open in the browser. After opening that, it started working. i was able to fetch the data from the directory API.
In the same way, when i deployed the war on a remote server, I got a link which i was supposed to open. But when i opened it(From my local system) , it didnt work.
I got could not connect to the server error.

How do i authorize the directory API access on a remote server so that i could fetch the data?

Thanks.

Comment: "it didnt work" is very vague. What error are you getting. Did you make sure you were connected to the internet thru a local web server?

Comment: I got 'could not connect to the server error.' I think its because its localhost of that remote server. But when i changed it to the remote IP address, it says it is a private IP, requires device ID and device name

Comment: make sure you have a working local server. Use python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080

Comment: My case is when the server is remote and i have to deploy the war there.